# how to change the iframe by a buttonclick in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i have a homepage and it has a iframe..i want that after clicking the button sign in..the particualr iframe will have the user.aspx..but how to implement this in code behind of the user.aspx.cs on buttonclick?? i want work it for server side...and i have learnt that javascript function can't be used as i am wanting it in server side..

my asp button and iframe in home.aspx

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="signin" CssClass="signinbt" Text="Sign in" OnClick="signin_Click"/>
    </div>
       <iframe id ="iframestyle" src="homeframe.aspx" name="iframe_a" runat="server" style="margin-top:0px;width:100%;height:500px;"></iframe>
   </div>
```

my codebehind

```
 protected void signin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   iframstyle.Attributes["src"] = "userpage.aspx"; 
}
```

here showing that iframestyle doesn't contain in the present context..

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
protected void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 iframestyle.Attributes["src"] = "homeframe.aspx"
 }
```

Comment: i am getting an error that iframestyle does not exist in the current context... @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1276697/mahmoude-elghandour

Comment: any button of the page which will be in the iframe of home.aspx can use the id of iframe???

Comment: <iframe src="Login.aspx" runat="server" id="frame" width="500px" height="500px"> </iframe>
You must use runat="server"

Comment: i have used runat="server" but i couldn't understand still it is showing the same error...

Comment: are the iframe and the button in same page or what ?

Comment: yes...
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="signin" CssClass="signinbt" Text="Sign in" OnClick="signin_Click"/>
        </div>
           <iframe id ="iframestyle" src="homeframe.aspx" name="iframe_a" runat="server" style="margin-top:0px;width:100%;height:500px;"></iframe>
       </div>

Comment: But one thing,how can i change the iframe of other page from a button click of other page...

Comment: search about how can findcontrol from other page :)tell me if you stuk